# Not getting ref inside function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, react-ref

Following is my source code in which I am trying to fetch the reference of my component and check if the click happens outside the component but I am getting error as its coming as undefined. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Code -

```
// @flow
import { PureComponent, createRef } from 'react';
import type { Props, State } from 'types';

class MyComponent extends PureComponent<Props, State> {
  static defaultProps = {
    myComponentBody: ''
  };

  state: State = {
    showMyComponent: false,
  };

  wrapperRef: { current: null | HTMLDivElement } = createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  handleClickOutside(e: SyntheticEvent<>) {
    console.log(`Inside --->`); // This function is triggering
    console.log(this); // I am getting #document whole html
    console.log(this.wrapperRef); // undefined
    console.log(wrapperRef); // Uncaught ReferenceError: wrapperRef is not defined
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(e.target)) {
      this.setState({
        showMyComponent: false,
      });
    }
  }

  handleClick(e: SyntheticEvent<>) {
    this.setState({
      showMyComponent: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { myComponentBody } = this.props;
    return (
      <div onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)} ref={this.wrapperRef}>
        {this.props.children}
        {this.state.showMyComponent && (
          <div>
            <div>{myComponentBody}</div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to access **this** which is the context of your current Class.

There are several approaches to this.

**1. bind your `handleClickOutside` in the constructor**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
}
```

**2. transform `handleClickOutside`, to be arrow function.**

```
  handleClickOutside = (e: SyntheticEvent<>) => {
    console.log(`Inside --->`); // This function is triggering
    console.log(this); // I am getting #document whole html
    console.log(this.wrapperRef); // undefined
    console.log(wrapperRef); // Uncaught ReferenceError: wrapperRef is not defined
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(e.target)) {
      this.setState({
        showMyComponent: false,
      });
    }
  }
```

**3. Or you can bind it at the click event**

```
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} ref={this.wrapperRef}>
        {this.props.children}
        {this.state.showMyComponent && (
          <div>
            <div>{myComponentBody}</div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: It works :) but I don't need to define it in a constructor and why handleClick works without arrow function ?

Comment: @Nesh You have to do one of the approaches. There are several ways you can bind your function to the class